# Agregar variable progresivo en PHP POST o GET

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quisiera saber como podría pasar variable progresivo
Por ejemplo:
Mi URL es: **urlejemplo.com/formulario?id=1528** 
Entonces quiero que al seleccionar un option, capture el dato del value y se pase a al url para que quede así :
**urlejemplo.com/formulario?id=1528&iddoc=132**
Hay una forma para que pase eso? Se le agradecería mucho.

```
<div class="form-group">
                          <h5>Terapista <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                          <div class="controls">
                            <select class="select2 form-control custom-select select-css" style="width: 100%; height:36px;" name="cbterapista" id="cbterapista" required data-validation-required-message="Campo Requerido" onchange="location = this.value;">
                                <option value="">-- SELECCIONA --</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Ese es mi codigo html para el select: Entonces estoy usando un onchange="location = this.value;" para poder enviar con este script de aqui:

```
<option value='&id_medicos=".$rowM2['id_medicos']."'>".$rowM2['me_nom']."</option>
```

Pero lo único que hace es actualizarme la pagina con el &id_medicos= y el id pero lo anterior no sale, y necesito que se ponga.
Estoy usando select dependientes, por eso no hay nada, pero si capta la id.

Estoy usando PHP

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? Por favor agrega un ejemplo [mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se ve en tu código, no estás actuando en el  con php. 
Yo intentaría algo así, con *echo*:

```
<option value="<?php echo "&id_medicos=".$rowM2['id_medicos']?>"> <?php echo $rowM2['me_nom']?></option>
```

O bien algo como

```
<?php
    // Inserto en el código para crear el *select*
    echo '
        <option value="&id_medicos=$rowM2[id_medicos]">$rowM2[me_nom]</option>
    ';
?>
```

Verifica en el navegador que el *option* escape realmente el value que buscas.
Por otra parte, creo que cuando dices "this.value" refieres al valor del *select*, no del *option*. Para hacer algo similar, yo he hecho algo así en javascript:

```
function valorOption(){
    var select = document.getElementById("selectID");
    var x = select.selectedIndex;
    var selected_option = document.getElementsByTag("option")[x];
    alert(selected_option.value);
}
```